# 405 error on PUT call from annotator js

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, jakarta-ee, weblogic-10.x

I am using annotator JS to send a PUT request to my url

http://localhost:7101/dashboard.do?op=updateAnnotation&token=123456789

However I am getting a 405 error when the JS tries to make this call.
I am able to send GET,POST requests but not PUT request.

I am using struts 1.3 dispatch action and not servlet with weblogic 10.

Comment: Looking at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes I guess the server you addressed just doesn't like "PUT" as a method. So this is a server-side problem, unrelated on how you did send it on client side. Perhaps try curl to send the request form command line, to see a difference, if any. And check the server logs.

Comment: should i be checking apache or weblogic ?

Comment: I don't know about your configuration, so, if in doubt, check both. I as of my experience with my own local configuration I would have a look at catalina.out, then at any other log in the tomcat directory (assuming your "apache" indicates you're using tomcat). Hope this helps.